# When to use RequestContextFilter with Jersey?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-boot, jersey, jersey-2.0

In a bunch of the tutorials and code samples of Spring Boot and Jersey that I've seen, the following line appears:

```
register(RequestContextFilter.class)
```

What is this really used for? I don't see anything unusual in those samples, and if I remove it from my (simple) application, nothing seems to break.

`RequestContextFilter`'s javadoc says

> This filter is mainly for use with third-party servlets, e.g. the JSF
>   FacesServlet. Within Spring's own web support, DispatcherServlet's
>   processing is perfectly sufficient.

I haven't seen third party servlets in those examples.

In [one of them](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/restful-web-services-example-in-java-with-jersey-spring-and-mybatis/) I read

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.spring.scope.RequestContextFilter, which
>   is a Spring filter that provides a bridge between JAX-RS and Spring
>   request attributes

What would be an example of a Spring request attribute?
What is some typical use case, besides needing a third party servlet?

Comment: Not exactly sure what RequestContextFilter class is don't but most commonly these are implementations of javax.servlet.filter to do things like setup a session before handling the actual request. Spring one that is common for OpenSessionInView which is a servlet filter that will open a Transaction before the request and either commit it or roll it back when the request is completed. There are lots of reasons to register a Filter.